# NoReverseMatch at /kwalificaties/ Reverse for 'updatekwalificatie' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

views.py

```
def updateKwalificatie (request, pk):
kwalificatie = Kwalificaties.objects.get(id=pk)
form = kwalificatie_beheer(instance=kwalificatie)
context = {'form': form}
return render(request,'accounts/kwalificatiebeheer.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
path('updateKwalificatie/<str:pk>/', views.updateKwalificatie, name='updatekwalificatie'),
```

kwalificaties.html tamplate

```
            <div class="card card-body">
                   <table class="table table-sm">
                      <tr>
                           <th>ID</th>
                          <th>E.H.B.O</th>
                          <th>Treinen</th>
                          <th>Extra</th>
                          <th>update</th>
                          <th>verwijder</th>
                      </tr>

                       {% for i in kwalificaties %}

                       <tr>
                           <td>{{i.naam}}</td>
                           <td>{{i.ehbo}}</td>
                           <td>{{i.treinen}}</td>
                           <td>{{i.extra}}</td>
                           <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" href="{% url 'updatekwalificatie' kwalificatie.id %}">Update</a></td>
                           <td><input type="submit" value="Verwijder"></td>
                       </tr>

                       {% endfor %}
```

heyi hope someone can help me with this error thx alot.....................................................................

Comment: Can you add the view that renders kwalificaties.html to your question? `kwalificatie` is not being added to the context correctly in that view

Comment: def kwalificaties (request):
    kwalificaties = Kwalificaties.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'accounts/kwalificaties.html',{'kwalificaties':kwalificaties})

Comment: Can you add the rest of kwalificaties.html, specifically the part where you loop over `kwalificaties`? When the link is rendered `kwalificatie.id` is None or empty string

Comment: i have some of the tamplate  is this good ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loop over `kwalificaties` in your template you name the loop variable/instance `i`, you need to use this name in your tag or change `i` to `kwalificatie`

```
{% for i in kwalificaties %}

                       <tr>
                           <td>{{i.naam}}</td>
                           <td>{{i.ehbo}}</td>
                           <td>{{i.treinen}}</td>
                           <td>{{i.extra}}</td>
                           <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" href="{% url 'updatekwalificatie' i.id %}">Update</a></td>
                           <td><input type="submit" value="Verwijder"></td>
                       </tr>

                       {% endfor %}
```